# java code to get all posts from Tumblr using the tag name

Tags: java, tags, fetch, tumblr

I have tried to get the posts from Tumblr using the tag.

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=hadoop&api_key=*****
```

I can write  HTTP client and can get the json and parse accordingly. But i want to know information like any supported tumblr java api to access this.

I tried with `com.tumblr.jumblr.JumblrClient` but i didnot found any method which supports this requirement. Can any one suggest me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found It..

```
public List<Post> fetchPostsByTag(JumblrClient client, String tagName, long timestamp) {
    if (client == null || tagName == null || tagName.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (timestamp != 0) {
        options.put("before", timestamp + "");
    }
    List<Post> posts = client.tagged(tagName, options);
    return posts;
}
```

This code is worked for me .. now i am getting more than 20 posts using tag.

Thanks Reins for support.

Answer (score 2):

If I look at the JumblrClient.java in github I can see a method:

```
/**
 * Tagged posts
 * @param tag the tag to search
 * @param options the options for the call (or null)
 * @return a list of posts
 */
public List<Post> tagged(String tag, Map<String, ?> options) {
    if (options == null) {
        options = Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    Map<String, Object> soptions = JumblrClient.safeOptionMap(options);
    soptions.put("api_key", apiKey);
    soptions.put("tag", tag);
    return requestBuilder.get("/tagged", soptions).getTaggedPosts();
}
```

https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tumblr/jumblr/JumblrClient.java

https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr#tagged

Based on documentation it should be exactly what you need. It actually builds the same request you have mentioned in your question.

EDIT:
Based on the Tumblr API documentation it is not possible to ask for more than 20 posts.

> limit - The number of results to return: 1–20, inclusive

https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#tagged-method

Comment: Thank you for information. But i am getting only top20 posts based on the tag which i pass to this method.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Tumblr API defines the limit as 1-20